# css class has-error not being added to div when radiobutton has validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC razor view page with a form and some fields with data annotations like this:

```
<form....>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BirthDay, Model.Days, "Día", new { @class = "form-control" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthDay)
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BirthMonth, Model.Months, "Mes", new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthMonth)
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BirthYear, Model.Years, "Año", new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthYear)
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="radio control-label">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female") Mujer</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label class="radio control-label">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male") Hombre</label>
         </div>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)
</div>
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

My problem is that when i click on submit, the fields with errors are validated with his respective error message but in the case of the RadioButtonFor fields, the style is different to the other form fields.
Inspecting the HTML i found that in the other fields i have on the main div `<div class="form-group has-error">` but in the radiobutton div i dont have the has-error class.
What's happening?
If i change the radiobuttonfor for another control such like textboxfor, the class is added to the div and the colors are the same.
[image]

Comment: I have experienced this same incredibly perplexing issue in a Razor page as well. If I submit a form with invalid fields, the output includes "has-error" in one of the form-group divs (the first one) but in none of the subsequent. If I change the string to anything else besides "has-error" (literally anything from changing one character to the entire string), it shows up in the div. **If you ever found the solution, would you please let me know what you did?**

Answer (score 1):

Check this, it was very helpful for me:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/euCdyWpCrKU

Ok! the solution that worked for me is about overwrite data annotation css class. So, for every validation detected by unobtrusive ajax js...the alert style will be something like this:

If you use less, it's quite easy. Just add to the end of bootstrap.less:

```
.validation-summary-errors
{
    .alert();
    .alert-danger();
}
.field-validation-error 
{
    .label();
    .label-danger();
}
```

If you use CSS, add the following code to your css file:

```
.validation-summary-errors
{
  /* alert classes */

  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;

  /* alert danger classes */
  color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;

}

.field-validation-error
{
  /* label classes */
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;

  /* label danger classes */
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

PD: Sorry about my poor english, i hope it help you!